# Calculate sequences of constantly increasing dates Spark

Tags: scala, date, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe in Spark with name column and dates. And I would like to find all continuous sequences of constantly increasing dates (day after day) for each name and calculate their durations. The output should contain a name, start date (of the dates sequence) and duration of such time period (amount of days)
How can I do this with Spark functions?

A consecutive sequence of dates example:

```
2019-03-12
2019-03-13
2019-03-14
2019-03-15
```

I have defined such solution but it calculates the overall amount of days by each name and does not divide it into sequences:

```
val result = allDataDf
    .groupBy($"name")
    .agg(count($"date").as("timePeriod"))
    .orderBy($"timePeriod".desc)
    .head()
```

Also, I tried with ranks, but counts column has only 1s, for some reason:

```
val names = Window
    .partitionBy($"name")
    .orderBy($"date")
 val result = allDataDf
    .select($"name", $"date", rank over names as "rank")
    .groupBy($"name", $"date", $"rank")
    .agg(count($"*") as "count")
```

The output looks like this:

```
+-----------+----------+----+-----+
|stationName|      date|rank|count|
+-----------+----------+----+-----+
|       NAME|2019-03-24|   1|    1|
|       NAME|2019-03-25|   2|    1|
|       NAME|2019-03-27|   3|    1|
|       NAME|2019-03-28|   4|    1|
|       NAME|2019-01-29|   5|    1|
|       NAME|2019-03-30|   6|    1|
|       NAME|2019-03-31|   7|    1|
|       NAME|2019-04-02|   8|    1|
|       NAME|2019-04-05|   9|    1|
|       NAME|2019-04-07|  10|    1|
+-----------+----------+----+-----+
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate max duration of the continuous periods of time Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56509478/calculate-max-duration-of-the-continuous-periods-of-time-spark)

Comment: Need better explanation

Comment: Can you give an example of what the input and output table should look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding consecutive dates is fairly easy in SQL. You could do it with a query like:

```
WITH s AS (
   SELECT
    stationName,
    date,
    date_add(date, -(row_number() over (partition by stationName order by date))) as discriminator
  FROM stations
)
SELECT
  stationName,
  MIN(date) as start,
  COUNT(1) AS duration
FROM s GROUP BY stationName, discriminator
```

Fortunately, we can use SQL in spark. Let's check if it works (I used different dates):

```
val df = Seq(
       ("NAME1", "2019-03-22"),
       ("NAME1", "2019-03-23"),
       ("NAME1", "2019-03-24"),
       ("NAME1", "2019-03-25"),

       ("NAME1", "2019-03-27"),
       ("NAME1", "2019-03-28"),

       ("NAME2", "2019-03-27"),
       ("NAME2", "2019-03-28"),

       ("NAME2", "2019-03-30"),
       ("NAME2", "2019-03-31"),

       ("NAME2", "2019-04-04"),
       ("NAME2", "2019-04-05"),
       ("NAME2", "2019-04-06")
  ).toDF("stationName", "date")
      .withColumn("date", date_format(col("date"), "yyyy-MM-dd"))

df.createTempView("stations");

  val result = spark.sql(
  """
     |WITH s AS (
     |   SELECT
     |    stationName,
     |    date,
     |    date_add(date, -(row_number() over (partition by stationName order by date)) + 1) as discriminator
     |  FROM stations
     |)
     |SELECT
     |  stationName,
     |  MIN(date) as start,
     |  COUNT(1) AS duration
     |FROM s GROUP BY stationName, discriminator
   """.stripMargin)

result.show()
```

It seems to output correct dataset:

```
+-----------+----------+--------+
|stationName|     start|duration|
+-----------+----------+--------+
|      NAME1|2019-03-22|       4|
|      NAME1|2019-03-27|       2|
|      NAME2|2019-03-27|       2|
|      NAME2|2019-03-30|       2|
|      NAME2|2019-04-04|       3|
+-----------+----------+--------+
```